# Change comment char based on filetype

Tags: vimscript

I am playing around with `asm`, which uses ATT syntax. For the filetype `asm`, vim is using the comment char `;`, though it should be `#`. How/where can I change the comment char per file type? Note that I am currently using NERDCommenter. I am looking to add something like:

```
autocmd Filetype asm comment='#'
```

Note, it looks like this is defined here in NERD_commenter.vim:

```
let s:delimiterMap = {
    \ 'asm': { 'left': ';', 'leftAlt': '#' },
    ...
```

But I'm not sure how/where to 'overwrite' this (other than modifying this code directly, which I don't want to do).

Comment: I think you're looking for the `comments` setting? I don't quite know how this all works, so you'll have to wait for someone else to give an answer, or you can try reading up on `:help comments` and see how far that gets you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin suggested, the definition of comment continuation characters happens in `'comments'` (and `'commentstring'`) settings. Comment related plugins like NerdCommenter/EnhancedCommentify/tComment(?)/... have their own way to define which sequences shall be used to comment existing blocks -- some of them use what is defined in `&comments` or `&commentstring`.

The easy solution would be to add a `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/asm/att.vim`  file in your configuration that expands default ASM settings with

```
setlocal comments+=:#
```

This way, `;`, `//` and `/*...*/` are still kept as comments.

If more differences exist, you may want instead to exploit vim default detection of asm flavour (see `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/dist/ft.vim`) by adding `# asmsyntax=attasm` in your files, and a `~/.vim/ftplugin/attasm.vim` that contains exactly what you want, and a syntax file that loads default asm syntax highlighting file (w/ `:runtime syntax/asm.vim`).

You may want to read `:h asm.vim`.

Note, I wonder whether the fact that `#` isn't configured as a continuation character is because it may have side effects with GAS preprocessor (according to this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29959235/15934)), and thus seen as a bad practice.