# Changing default comment characters in NERDCommenter

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdcommenter

I've asked a [similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26702/change-comment-char-based-on-filetype) in the past but haven't been able to solve it in too nice a manner. the only way I've been able to figure out how to change the delimiter is by modifying the NERDCommenter source itself:

```
# plugin/NERD_commenter.vim
let s:delimiterMap = {
    ...
    \ 'asm': { 'left': '#', 'leftAlt': ';' },
    ...
}
```

I would prefer to do something like this so it sits in my vimrc (or some other place so that if I move this to another machine it still works):

```
augroup AsmComments
   autocmd!
   autocmd Filetype asm let b:NERDCommenterDelims['left'] = '#'
augroup END
```

What would be the proper way to do this?

---

**Update**: By the way, I just typed in the following command (in the question) and pasted that into vim and it worked, so I think my problem should be fixed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `g:NERDCustomDelimiters` to a Dict with your overrides. You can set it in your vimrc:

```
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {
    \ 'asm': { 'left': '#', 'leftAlt': ';' }
    \ }
```

If this variable is defined when NERDCommenter is loaded, it will [extend its delimiter map with it](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter/blob/fade3d4b26f5a0d58f256a06ba7b0a04d9fb4f3b/plugin/NERD_commenter.vim#L481,L483).

NERDCommenter also documents this variable under its [`:help 'NERDCustomDelimiters'`](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter/blob/fade3d4b26f5a0d58f256a06ba7b0a04d9fb4f3b/doc/NERD_commenter.txt#L650):

> Use this option if you have new filetypes you want the script to handle, or if you want to override the default delimiters of a filetype.

---

The problem with overriding `b:NERDCommenterDelims`, as you suggested in the question, is that it needs to happen *after* the `autocmd` from NERDCommenter that initially sets it, so that block is unlikely to work if set in your vimrc...

You could make it work by storing it in a `after/` directory, for instance `~/.vim/after/plugin/nerd_commenter_overrides.vim` or similar.

(Ideally, creating an `ftplugin` named `asm.vim` would be better than creating an `autocmd` explicitly, but I'm afraid in this case it would probably get executed before the `autocmd` from NERDCommenter and wouldn't work either... In any case, the global Dict override is the way to go!)

Comment: Thanks, this is great. The only solution that I found that works consistently -- thanks!